# Oracle.OLEDB not visible in 32 bit SSMS 2008

Tags: oracle, ssms, odac

This is my first post on here.

I'm having trouble creating a linked server in SSMS because Oracle is not listed as a provider.

However, in BIDS the Oracle provider is visible. I can connect to my database just fine.

It appears that BIDS is 64 bit and SSMS is 32 bit so I downloaded 32 bit Oracle ODAC but the provider is still not visible.

I'm at my wits end here so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a full oracle client installed on the server,  with Oracle ODAC 11.2.0.3 you may have to select "Oracle Provider for OLE DB" when installing (i.e. not ticked by default I think.)